# What's the namespace used for wordnet in an ontology?

Tags: namespaces, ontology, wordnet

Like I've a word such as "India" and Wordnet has the information of type of entity that I've at hand, how can I refer to wordnet for this specific type of entity? Like, I extract the information that India is-a country, how will I write this based on wordnet? What namespace to use? Note that I'm not in search of countries ontology but rather want to refer lexical dictionary in my ontology. How can I do that? any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wordnet 3.0 in RDF](http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/lod/wn30/), WordNet 3.0 users the following namespace: http://purl.org/vocabularies/princeton/wn30/.

If you are after WordNet 2.0, you may use the one hosted on w3.org: http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20. The documentation is here: http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/BestPractices/WNET/wn-conversion.

Quoting from the [Related Projects page](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/) of the WordNet official website, someone provided a large, standalone OWL file:

> Adam Pease has announced that WordNet
>   is now available in OWL with links to
>   the [Suggested Upper Merged Ontology](http://www.ontologyportal.org/) as
>   [a single large OWL file](http://www.ontologyportal.org/WordNet.owl) and
>   dynamically served as OWL pages
>   comprising single synset at a time
>   (e.g.physical_object).